# Command to execute file stops all process .bat after its closed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

Im using a **windowns 10 bash command**, when i use:

```
SET WAY_TO_EXECUTABLE=python.exe

cmd /K %WAY_TO_EXECUTABLE%
```

...

The process stops after close the installation of executable but i have other things to do after that. Resuming, how can i force continue the .bat process after closed the installation of executable?

is there another script to do that and continue?

Comment: I don't think that is a 'bash' command.

Comment: "cmd /K C:\Python\Python.exe" for example.. It runs a .exe in windowns using cmd.

Comment: Do you know the difference between bash and batch?

Comment: Better, do you know the difference between [Windows bash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and [Windows Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Windows_NT)?

Answer (score 0):

just use: `start /WAIT %WAY_TO_EXECUTABLE%`

So, when .exe close the process in .bat continues.